# Проблема сохранения модели

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Есть проблема при сохранении модели.
Вот мои связанные модели.

Mark:

```
public class Mark
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Марка")]
        public string MarkName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<CarModel> CarModels { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Car> Cars { get; set; }

        public Mark()
        {
            CarModels = new List<CarModel>();
            Cars = new List<Car>();
        }
    }
```

CarModel:

```
public class CarModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Модель")]
        public string ModelName { get; set; }

        public int MarkId { get; set; }
        public virtual Mark Mark { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Equipment> Equipments { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Car> Cars { get; set; }

        public CarModel()
        {
            Equipments = new List<Equipment>();
            Cars = new List<Car>();
        }
    }
```

Equipment:

```
public class Equipment
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        //Двигатель
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Двигатель")]
        public int Engine { get; set; }
        //Количество лошадиных сил
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Мощность")]
        public int Power { get; set; }
        //Год выпуска
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Год выпуска")]
        public int ReleaseYear { get; set; }
        //Тип привода
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Тип привода")]
        public string DriveType { get; set; }
        //КПП
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "КПП")]
        public string Transmission { get; set; }
        //Кузов
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Кузов")]
        public string Body { get; set; }
        //Максимальная скорость
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Максимальная скорость")]
        public int MaxSpeed { get; set; }
        //Вес
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Вес")]
        public int Weight { get; set; }
        //Бак
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Бак")]
        public int MaxFuelVolume { get; set; }
        //Цвет автомобиля
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Цвет")]
        public string Color { get; set; }
        //Изорбражение автомобиля
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Изображение автомобиля")]
        public string Picture { get; set; }

        public int CarModelId { get; set; }
        public virtual CarModel CarModel { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Car> Cars { get; set; }

        public Equipment()
        {
            Cars = new List<Car>();
        }
    }
```

Car:

```
public class Car
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Цена")]
        public int Price { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Количество на складе")]
        public int Count { get; set; }

        public int? MarkId { get; set; }
        public virtual Mark Mark { get; set; }

        public int CarModelId { get; set; }
        public virtual CarModel CarModel { get; set; }

        public int? EquipmentId { get; set; }
        public virtual Equipment Equipment { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }

        public Car()
        {
            Orders = new List<Order>();
        }
    }
```

Так вот если я добавляю новый автомобиль и при этом сразу же новую марку, модель и комплектацию, сохранение проходит хорошо, создаётся марка, к ней привязывается модель, к модели комплектация, и ниже создаётся сущность автомобиль с привязками ко всему этому.

Вот код для примера:

```
Context db = new Context();
            Equipment equip = new Equipment() { Body = "Седан", Color = "Красный", DriveType = "Передний", Engine = 1600,
                                                MaxFuelVolume = 60, MaxSpeed = 250, Picture = "Картинка", Power = 150,
                                                ReleaseYear = 2015, Transmission = "Автомат", Weight = 2000 };
            Mark mark = new Mark() { MarkName = "BMW" };
            CarModel carModel = new CarModel() { ModelName = "M3" };
            Car car = new Car();
            car.Mark = mark;
            car.CarModel = carModel;
            car.Equipment = equip;

            unitOfWOrk.Cars.Create(car);
            unitOfWOrk.Save();
```

Но если я пытаюсь создать автомобиль и привязать к нему существующую марку и существующую модель, но новую комплектацию выходит ошибка

> An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

Вот код примера:

```
Context db = new Context();
            Equipment equip = new Equipment() { Body = "Седан", Color = "Красный", DriveType = "Передний", Engine = 1600,
                                                MaxFuelVolume = 60, MaxSpeed = 250, Picture = "Картинка", Power = 150,
                                                ReleaseYear = 2015, Transmission = "Автомат", Weight = 2000 };
            Car car = new Car();
            car.MarkId = 1;
            car.CarModelId = 1;
            car.Equipment = equip;
```

Как я понимаю ругается на `public int CarModelId { get; set; }` в модели `Equipment`, потому что я пробовал сделать `int?` и тогда этой ошибки нет.
Так вот вопрос в том, почему при создании новых данных entity догадывается что к чему нужно привязать, а в случае с добавлением новых данных, такого не происходит?

Comment: А приведите сообщение внутреннего исключения

Comment: @Cost `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Equipments_dbo.CarModels_CarModelId". The conflict occurred in database "D:\AUTOSTORE\AUTOSTORE\APP_DATA\AUTOSTOREDB.MDF", table "dbo.CarModels", column 'Id'.
The statement has been terminated.`

Comment: проверьте наличие в таблице `CarModels` записи с `Id = 1`, такое исключение обычно возникает, когда такой записи нет. Поле автоинкрементное, вы могли добавить запись, потом ее удалить, а при новом добавлении `Id` уже не будет равен 1

Comment: @Cost это всё есть, проблема не в этом.